# Jquery problem animation or not animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

First of all I'm new to jquery, so I don't know if it's possible, hence my question.

I have a problem to solve, but my doubt is it possible to solve it without animation or I will have to switch to animation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready( function() {
        
    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
            }
        });
            
    $( "div" ).html( " <table class='table'><tbody><tr class='active'> <td><span>Row 1</span></td><td><span>Row 1 </span></td> <td><span>Row 1</span></td></tr></tbody></table>" );
    })
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.active{
    background-color:gray;
}

.inactive{
    background-color:white ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what seems to go wrong? See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some useful tips.

Comment: What do you mean with animation or not animation?

Comment: Not animation  use css animations

Comment: i'm trying to do something like that but using only jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/vmu0p2oe/    where when selecting the table it removes the active part and adds the inactive part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").html(" <table class='table'><tbody><tr class='active'> <td><div class='row active'>Row 1</div></td><td><div class='row'>Row 1 </div></td> <td><div class='row'>Row 1</div></td></tr></tbody></table>");

  $('.row').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).toggleClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('inactive');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: gray;
}

.inactive {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

You can switch color. Please check this

Comment: Thanks I kind of modified something in your code and it turned out the way I wanted. `tr class='row active'> <td>Row 1</td><td>Row 1 </td>` instead of being per item i changed it to be by the whole row